# How to use Pyscript (or Python) in Blogger?

Tags: javascript, python, html, math, blogger

I found a youtube tutorial about using Pyscript in Blogger: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eL95WluhLGA. The problem is anytime I use

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css"/>
    <script defer 
src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"> 
</script>
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
```

Both keep forcing me to download pydiode, and my blogspot page just keep loading. Not showing the python script. How to use pyscript in Blogger to run Python code? I want to use Numpy and matplotlib for teaching how to graph some physics measurements. Thank you.

Edit: it seems like sympy library is not compatible yet. But somehow when I want to print "Now you can", it still display the code not the string it self.

[image]